# Derive Bazel label from source file path

Tags: bazel

Given a path to a source file within the workspace, how can I derive the label that Bazel uses to refer to the file. This seems to depend on what packages exist. For example, if I have this structure:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
└── src
    └── bar
        └── foo.go
```

Then the label for `src/bar/foo.go` is `//src/bar/foo.go`. However, if I have this structure:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
└── src
    ├── BUILD
    └── bar
        ├── BUILD
        └── foo.go
```

Then the label for the same file is `//src/bar:foo.go`.

Is there a way to get Bazel to tell me what the label that identifies a file is, or must I to derive it based on the presence/absence of `BUILD` files at various levels of the workspace tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a valid label exists for `path/to/file.txt`, running `bazel query path/to/file.txt` will return you the absolute label.

e.g. for the first example:

```
$ bazel query src/bar/foo.go
//:src/bar/foo.go
```

and for the second example:

```
$ bazel query src/bar/foo.go
//src/bar:foo.go
```

If the file is not referenced in any rule (`filegroup`, `exports_files`, etc) in any BUILD file, it will not have a label.

Comment: Thanks for this and for clarifying the inaccuracies in my question  While I can see this will work in general it does feel like a bit of a kludge, and somewhat fragile. Is there no way to get Bazel to tell you which label represents a given file, or to derive it statically?

Comment: Of course, `bazel query` is the answer :-) updated my answer.

Comment: Amazing  I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't think of this since it's so simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jin is there a way to identify all the targets that have the file as a src within one command, rather than the two `bazel query` commands suggested in the [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html#what-rule-target-s-contain-file-path-to-file-bar-java-as-a-sourc)

Comment: @petros-eskinder Kinda, using `let var = expr in ...`. See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5584